# Playing a Wild Draw Color Card on top of another Wild Draw Color Card to get out of drawing cards in UNO FLIP

Tags: uno, uno-flip

If a player lays down a Wild Draw Color Card, can the next player lay down their own Wild Draw Color Card to get out of drawing cards.
I argued that this should be allowed since it's like in UNO playing a Draw Two Card and the next player then plays another Draw Two Card.

Comment: What do you mean by "picking"? Do you mean drawing?

Comment: It's the same kind of question, but a different card game (UNO vs UNO FLIP).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not valid to do so since according to the [Mattel's UNO FLIP! rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDR44-English.pdf) the next player:

> *Wild Draw Color Card (DARK SIDE)*
>      ... must draw until they get a color of your choosing (no matter how many cards they have to draw to do so) and lose their turn.
>
> *Wild Draw 2 Card (LIGHT SIDE)*
>     ... must draw two cards from the DRAW pile and lose their turn.

*But for the player after the next player (who had to pick up the cards) it's a valid play.*

*Note: Stacking or Progressive UNO, i.e. playing a Draw +1/+5 Card on top of another Draw +1/+5 Card without first drawing card is **not allowed**, but it's a common house rule used by many.*

> Draw One / Five Card
>   the next player **must draw** one / five card and **miss their turn**